# Symfony 4 map disabling not working

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

I'm trying to put two different entities (employee and contractor) in one selectbox (EntityType). So I created an unmapped entity called Receiver that puts all the loaded entities in one collection.

When debugging everything goes well, but as soon as it creates the form it gives me the following exception:

`Class "App\Receiver\Receiver" seems not to be a managed Doctrine entity. Did you forget to map it?`

And it indeed is not a managed Doctrine entity because it should only exist in the code. So in my type I've added the `mapped => false` option, however it still gives me that same exception.

Here is some code:

OrderController.php where the overall form is being built and a collection type is made

```
->add('orderNotes', CollectionType::class, [
               'entry_type' => NotesType::class,
               'allow_add' => true,
               'allow_delete' => true,
               'prototype' => true,
               'by_reference' => false,
               'required' => false,
               'label' => false,
                'mapped' => false
           ])
```

And here is the NotesType Form

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $options['mapped'] = false;
        $data = array_merge($data, Receiver::loadData($this->entityManager->getRepository("App:Contractor")->findAll(), "name", "id"));
        $data = array_merge($data, Receiver::loadData($this->entityManager->getRepository("App:Employee")->findAll(), "name", "id"));

        $builder
            ->add('body', TextareaType::class, ['attr' => ['class' => 'form-control']])
            ->add('receiver', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Receiver::class,
                'data' => $data,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'choice_value' => "value",
                'placeholder' => '- Selecteer -',
                'required' => false,
                'mapped' => false,
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => WorkorderNote::class,
            'mapped' => false,
        ]);
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

    }
```

So I have changed `mapped` to `false` about everywhere I know. So if you could please help me with this weird problem I would be very glad.

Kind regards

Comment: The [mapped option](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#mapped) is for something completely different.  Dead end there.  The EntityType is a Doctrine specific class and, if you check the code, it really seems to want to do a query.  You don't need a query so use the normal choice type.  You will need to adjust the way you build your data array.

Comment: Oh my god, if you didn't tell me that I would've been searching for days! Problem solved, thank you very much!